# If directory has no files then ... - Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, if-statement, command-line

I'm looking to see if a directory has no files in it or not. I do not want to take folders into account.

Right now I have `ls -1ap | grep -v / | wc -l` which will give me the number of files in the directory, but I cant seem to incorporate that into an if statement.

`if` `ls -1ap | grep -v / | wc -l` `< 1; then echo "one"; else echo "two"; fi`

Is there anything I can tweak a bit to get this to work? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ `ls -1ap | grep -v / | wc -l` == 0 ]; then echo empty; fi
```

And what you are looking for is `man test` (that's the `[')

Note that I didn't look into whether your condition is optimal, just rewrote it in test-form.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter:

`[ ! "$(ls -A /path/to/directory)" ] && echo "Empty" || echo "Not Empty"`